# Would anyone refactor a URL change better than the way I do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, refactoring

Not sure if this is inapropriate albeit it working fine.

In order to move to a new location and retain the root URL, I do examples like this :

```
window.location = window.location.href.split('/oldbar')[0] + '/foobar/' + $value

window.location = window.location.href.split(/oldbar/)[0] + 'foobar';

window.location = window.location.href.split('/oldbar')[0] + '/foobar/'
```

Would you do it differently? If so how / why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to split up the href when you can just access the `pathname` property of the [location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location):

```
// not really sure what you're trying to do, but...
window.location.pathname = window.location.pathname + "/foobar/";
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Comment: I think he means to _replace_ `oldbar` with `foobar`

Answer (score 0):

To retain the root URL, just manipulate `window.location.pathname`, not the whole `href` property.